# Drag down formula from last row with formula to next, until "A" ends

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that i have big Excel file and need to drag down formulas as i copy values, I explain it further with an example table:
[image]

I have a vba script running in the background that on execution copys missing data from another datasheet, this copy procedure is in a For Each and in there i want to also copy down the formulas from the last row where there are formulas from the Range D:F.
For those who want to see it, this is my copy function:

```
If rowNotFoundMain = True Then
    If cell2.Offset(0, 7).Value = 0 Then     ' Offset 7, sind die Ehrungen
        cell2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Set rFirstBlank = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ws2.Range(cell2.Address, cell2.Offset(0, 2).Address).Copy
        rFirstBlank.PasteSpecial

        ' INSERT DRAG DOWN FUNCTION HERE '

    End If
End If
```

I looked up various ways on the Internet but didn't find suitable answers for my problem.
Why am I asking this directly for an answer and can't help anyhow ? Simple, I can program in theory but never used VBA, my boss wants this from me and I am searching everything together from the web.
I hope my explanation makes sense and if you need further Information, please don't hesitate and ask away.
Have a nice week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select D2:F6 range
2. Double-click black square in the bottom right hand side corner
3. Your formulas are copied!
4. Now do the same while recording a macro
5. Check recorded result and adopt to your case.

Comment: Thanks very much, never thought of such an "easy" way to do it!